# Order update email exception in magento2

Tags: magento2, email, sales-order

I tried below code to get items from order in email template `order_update.html`

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order area="frontend"}}
```

but above one not working for me , so i tried like below,

```
 {{block class='Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\Template' area='frontend' template='Magento_Sales::email/items.phtml' order=$order"}}
```

This one throws error like below,

```
exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'Missing required argument $debugHintsPath
```

if anybody have idea means please tell me

Answer (score 0):

You only need to pass in the missing parameter **order_id** to the template to use **sales_email_order_items** to display the **order item grid**

1. create vendor/module_name/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        
        <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderCommentSender" type="vendor\module_name\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderCommentSender" />
    
    </config>
```

2. create vendor/module_name/Model/Order/Email/Sender/OrderCommentSender.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace vendor\module_name\Model\Order\Email\Sender;

use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderCommentIdentity;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\Template;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\NotifySender;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;

/**
 * Class OrderCommentSender
 */
class OrderCommentSender extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderCommentSender
{
    /**
     * @var Renderer
     */
    protected $addressRenderer;

    /**
     * Application Event Dispatcher
     *
     * @var ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $eventManager;

    /**
     * Send email to customer
     *
     * @param Order $order
     * @param bool $notify
     * @param string $comment
     * @return bool
     */
    public function send(Order $order, $notify = true, $comment = '')
    {
        $this->identityContainer->setStore($order->getStore());

        $transport = [
            'order' => $order,
            'order_id' => $order->getId(),
            'comment' => $comment,
            'billing' => $order->getBillingAddress(),
            'store' => $order->getStore(),
            'formattedShippingAddress' => $this->getFormattedShippingAddress($order),
            'formattedBillingAddress' => $this->getFormattedBillingAddress($order),
            'order_data' => [
                'customer_name' => $order->getCustomerName(),
                'frontend_status_label' => $order->getFrontendStatusLabel()
            ]
        ];
        $transportObject = new DataObject($transport);

        /**
         * Event argument `transport` is @deprecated. Use `transportObject` instead.
         */
        $this->eventManager->dispatch(
            'email_order_comment_set_template_vars_before',
            ['sender' => $this, 'transport' => $transportObject->getData(), 'transportObject' => $transportObject]
        );

        $this->templateContainer->setTemplateVars($transportObject->getData());

        return $this->checkAndSend($order, $notify);
    }
}
```

3. run the following command：

> sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade && sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US -f && php bin/magento indexer:reindex && php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush && sudo chmod 777 * -R

4. use it in **order_update.html**

   `{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order_id=$order_id area="frontend"}}`

Note that the parameter passed in **sales_email_order_items** is **$order_i**d, using **$order** will be invalid